# Do custom metadata types not support COUNT(fieldName) with a GROUP BY?

Tags: custom-metadata, group-by, count

Question title covers most of it. Here's a sample query and the error I receive in response:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM MyCustom__mdt GROUP BY MyField__c
```

> field Id does not support aggregate operator COUNT

Also experimented with other permutations:

```
SELECT COUNT(DeveloperName) FROM MyCustom__mdt GROUP BY MyField__c
SELECT COUNT(QualifiedApiName) FROM MyCustom__mdt GROUP BY MyField__c
SELECT COUNT(MasterLabel) FROM MyCustom__mdt GROUP BY MyField__c
SELECT COUNT(MyField__c) FROM MyCustom__mdt GROUP BY MyField__c
```

No luck.

Now this works, but it's not the same query and doesn't satisfy what I'm trying to do (the GROUP BY is important to me):

```
    SELECT COUNT() FROM MyCustom__mdt
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GROUP BY does not seem to be supported for queries on custom metadata. If you refer to the [Custom Metadata Type Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_limitations.htm&type=5), the allowed SOQL syntax does not include GROUP BY.

```
SELECT fieldList [...]
FROM objectType
    [USING SCOPE filterScope]
[WHERE conditionExpression]
[ORDER BY field {ASC|DESC} [NULLS {FIRST|LAST}] ]
```

Comment: Ah, yep, looks like GROUP BY is not listed in the documentation. What's interesting then, is that COUNT() *does* work, despite being undocumented.

Comment: COUNT() is part of *fieldList* as documented in the [SOQL Syntax documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm). So that’s the reason it works.